# How do you programmatically execute javascript as if from the browser bar?

Tags: java, javascript

For example if you type in the browser bar `javascript:alert('hai');` it shows a pop up.  Is that possible to do in a programming language?

For example in java would I be able to connect to a website, and execute it's javascript somehow in my program?

Example:

Javascript in website:

```
function setStatus(a) {
    if (a == 1) status1 = true;
    else if (a == 2) status2 = true;
    else if (a == 3) status3 = true
}
```

Java program:

```
URL site = new URL("http://somesite.com/page.html");
URLConnection siteConnect = site.openConnection();
siteConnect.connect();
```

Would I be able to execute `setStatus(1)` `setStatus(2)` `setStatus(3)` inside the java program? How could it be done?

Comment: You would need to embed a browser into your Java program (or simply call it externally).

Comment: Does the downloaded code need to be JavaScript? Could you just download and compile Java code (being wary of security issues of course)? http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2006/jw-0612-dynamic.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for an environment that includes both a Javascript engine and the browser DOM and JS builtins; therefore your easiest bet is going to be something like a browser.

First stop for you should probably be [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) , which has [Javascript support](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/javascript.html) via Rhino and provides all the browser-specific JS objects. That may be everything you need.

If you want to go deeper, you could hook into a full browser engine by developing against Webkit. Two ports to look at are [QtWebkit](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKit) (if speed is not a criteria for you) or Google's [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/developers). Beware that setting either of those up will be a time investment.

Answer (score 1):

Not with just plain Java. Your browser can do that because it has a Javascript runtime installed, Java doesn't have that by default.

One option you may want to consider is [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/), a Javascript implementation in Java. You'd be able to run most standard Javascript this way, however anything that interacts with the browser's DOM (like the `window` object) may not work correctly.

Comment: What programmatic method could achieve this, do you know?